How to navigate inside initState() in Flutter
@override
void initState() {
final Future<bool> is_initialized = IsInitialized();

if (is_initialized == false) {
  GenerateDefaultPreferences();
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LanguageSelection())); //?
} else {
  SynchronizeDLIfSet();
}
  }

This is in my stateless widget. How can I navigate inside an initState() in Flutter?
I am trying to make it navigate to LanguageSelection() if the app didn't initialize before.

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  final Future<bool> is_initialized = IsInitialized();

  is_initialized.then((value) {
    if (!value) {
      GenerateDefaultPreferences();
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LanguageSelection()));
      });
    } else {
      SynchronizeDLIfSet();
    }
  });
}


You cannot have initState method in Stateless widget.
The initState() is a method that is called when an object for your stateful widget is created and inserted inside the widget tree. It is basically the entry point for the Stateful Widgets. To sum up, your widget must be Stateful.
Further explanation and example:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-initstate/
